# How to Create Synonym on Redshift by SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, synonym

I'm toally new to Redshift and plase allow me to ask a very basic question.
I'm just wondering if it's possible or not to creat synonym by command line (like SQL Server and Oracle) .

Although I understand we can create synonym by AWS console as follows;

Creating Synonyms With Amazon Redshift
https://webfocusinfocenter.informationbuilders.com/wfappent/TLs/TL_server/source/amazon_rs5.htm

May I ask any alternative way to manage them by scripts, like ’INHERIT' of PostgresSQL?

If possible, we'd be grateful if you kindly let us know it with any sample query.

Thank you.

Comment: No.  But what do you want to use a synonym for?  There may be an alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt comment, @MatBailie. We need synonym since we connect Redshift DWH table by ODBC for our BI (MicroStrategy). On ODBC, seems

Comment: On ODBC, seems.... ?

Comment: Sorry ! Sent it mistakingly, @MatBailie. We need synonym since we connect Redshift DWH tables by ODBC for our BI (MicroStrategy) and it requires unique table name under current MicroStrategy project. With Redshift ODBC, it can select only one table catalog and default database, but we'd like to divide several databases under one table catalog. Current SQL Server DWH, we're using synonyms for tables from several databases and looking for any appropriate alternative way for coming replacement to Redshift. I'd be grateful If you have any further idea. Thank you so much.

Comment: Views? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=825909

Comment: Many thanks again, @MatBailie. We'll verify this especially for our special views.  I really appreciate your prompt and useful advice!!

Comment: microstrategy works with schemas just fine - read the docs or raise a question on that

Comment: Thanks for your useful advice, @Jon Scott. I guess KB41809 is good example to use db schema name on MicroStrategy. If there is any misunderstanding, please let me know. Thank you!